# Is it possible to find someone else's deleted question containing my comments?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Happened already twice today (the second time the OP even have created a new account): I added my comments in one of the new questions, then OP had his question deleted and posted a very similar new question.

I wanted to tell OP not to post same question again, but to be sure I wanted to check deleted question. And since it's deleted I can't find it anymore.

Is there a way to find the question somehow?

Ideally I should be able to go to my `Activity - All actions - Comments`, find my comment there and the question. But comments to deleted questions seem to be removed as well from my activity.

Comment: Only your browser history or a mod can help here.

Comment: @rene, browsing history is amazing tip, stupid me.

Comment: why didn't you mod flag the question and explain it

Comment: Another workaround - you can subscribe to the RSS feed for the questions you're interested in. Then you get sort of a history of all posted questions. IIRC, the feeds update every five or ten minutes, so it's not *quite* real-time and you *might* miss a question if it's posted and deleted between updates. But it can serve to find a question that was deleted. It still not ideal but it's one way to find recently(-ish) deleted questions.

Comment: @nbk, flagging as what? I don't think mods have to step in for such minor issues. I would indeed vote-close new question as duplicate to previous OP question if it was not deleted.

Comment: @VLAZ, I don't know/never used RSS feeds. But browser history serves good, the only problem it will not stay for long.

Comment: @Sinatr  if you think that the new user account is only a dup,to ask the question again, the system administration can take a look at it, else they never notoce unless someone makes bigger missatkes

Comment: @Sinatr If you voted on the question, that will be recorded in your voting activity.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I didn't vote. But if my list of votes is not affected by deleting question, then it could be an alternative way to find deleted one. Though obviously I am not going to up-/down- vote all questions I comment to have this alternative always ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton, does it actually work like you think? I can't find a single entry in my downvote list which leads to deleted post.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure upvotes and downvotes that are made get removed from the activity table when the post gets deleted. It's only delete/undelete/close/reopen votes for which deleted posts still show up as a table row by default.

Comment: @Sinatr Ah, yes, it looks like it's just if you flagged the question (e.g. voted to close) or voted to delete it and it was subsequently deleted (the entry gets a pink background) that you can still easily go to it.

Comment: You can also look in the google cache.

Answer (score 9):

My [Comment History Checker](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Comment-History-Checker) userscript saves records for all comments made, and re-populates the [comments tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr?tab=activity&sort=comments) with the rows that are missing due to the post being deleted, which'll allow you to navigate back to the post later (for those who have the privilege to view deleted posts). Screenshot:

[image]

With the userscript, I can click on that pink deleted post link and get to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67538362), for example.

Of course, for this method to work, you must have had it installed *before* making the comments.

Comment: Local database sounds like an overkill for such an occasional task I require. I wonder if SO database can be used to pull the same info? Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: @Sinatr [don't you know that you are on SO](https://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/11/03/guys-who-overdo-it-on-stackoverflow/)